# Can I use the Nikon D810 battery with the D7100?

Tags: nikon, battery, nikon-d7100, nikon-d810

Can I use Nikon D810 battery on Nikon D7100?

And can you charge your camera while connected to the computer and with the battery inside the camera?

Comment: Related: [How can I run a Nikon DSLR from AC power?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/76091/11924)

Answer (score 3):

> Can I use the Nikon D810 battery with the D7100?

Yes<sup>*</sup>, you can use the EN-EL15 battery with both the D810 and the D7100. Both cameras use the EN-EL15 battery internally.

- From [Nikon's D7100 spec page](http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/d7100/spec.htm):

  > Battery: One EN-EL15 Rechargeable Li-ion Battery
- From [Nikon's D810 spec page](http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/d810/spec.htm):

  > Battery: One EN-EL15 Rechargeable Li-ion Battery

<sup>*</sup> : I caveated the "yes" answer because if you use the MB-D12 battery power pack / grip on the D810, you have the option of using a larger, more powerful EN-EL18/EN-EL18a battery in the grip. This battery is not compatible with the D7100, or its companion MD-D15 grip.

---

> Can you charge your camera while connected to the computer and with the battery inside the camera?

No, neither camera has battery charging circuitry inside the camera. You must charge the battery with a camera battery charger, such as the one that came with the camera.

For tethered operation, it is common to power the camera from a wall power adapter, such as the [EP-5B Power Supply Connector](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/nikon-products/product/power-packs/ep-5b-power-supply-connector.html) for Nikon bodies that use EN-EL15 batteries, with the EH-5a Power Supply.

I recommend *not* buying the Nikon-branded adapters. They're very expensive, and third-party adapters work just fine.